# How to make HTTP requests in AngularJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, http, angular

I just want to know how i can make http requests in the new angularjs 2.0 and how to hook this service to a controller.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now the http module/component is still under development and not yet released. In the interim there are two alternatives to use:

- fetch (https://github.com/github/fetch)
- axios (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

You can learn more about the new http service(s)S here:

- https://github.com/jeffbcross/http-design
- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DMacL7iwjSMPP0ytZfugpU4v0PWUK0BT6lhyaVEmlBQ/edit

Answer (score 5):

I think that basic support was already added. Basing on this [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/examples/src/http):

1. Bootstrap your app with httpInjectables from 'angular2/http' //index.ts
2. Have Http it injected in the constructor constructor(http: Http) //http_comp.ts
3. `http.get('./people.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(people => this.people = people);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excerpt:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http';
import {bootstrap} 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES,NgFor} from 'angular/common';

    @Component({
       selector: 'app'
    })

    @View({
        templateUrl: 'devices.html',
        directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES,NgFor]
    })

    export class App {
        devices: any;
        constructor(http: Http) {
            this.devices = []; 
            http.get('./devices.json').toRx().subscribe(res => this.devices = res.json());
        }
    }

    bootstrap(App,[HTTP_BINDINGS]);
```

Here is a repo that demonstrates angular2 http features that might come handy:

https://github.com/kaalpurush/ng2-http